# Java: Finding the largest chain in a Collatz sequence

Tags: java, collatz

I cannot find what's wrong for Project Euler problem #14. My first step was finding the algorithm, which worked until the numbers hit around 120000. The code broke and realized that I needed to use BigIntegers. I converted my algorithm to meet that change, but now it does not work.

I've added the System.out.print(chain_length) to assist me in where my code can potentially break.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger target = new BigInteger("1000000");
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger("0");

    final BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");
    final BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    final BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    final BigInteger three = new BigInteger("3");
    final BigInteger ten = new BigInteger("10");

    int greatest_index = 0;
    int greatest_length = 0;
    int chain_length = 0;

    BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2");
    for(i.equals(2) ; i.compareTo(target) == -1 ; i = i.add(one)) {
        n = i;
        chain_length = 1;
        while(n.compareTo(one) == -1) {
            chain_length++;
            if(n.mod(ten).equals(zero) == true){//even
                n = n.divide(two);
            }else{//odd
                n = n.multiply(three);
                n = n.add(one);
            }
            if(n.equals(one) == true && chain_length > greatest_length){
                greatest_length = chain_length;
                greatest_index = i.intValue();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(chain_length);
    }
    System.out.println(greatest_index);        
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need `BigInteger`s, `long` is enough.

Answer (score 7):

To test if a number is even you use modulo 2, not 10. Change this line:

```
if(n.mod(ten).equals(zero) == true){//even
```

To this:

```
if(n.mod(two).equals(zero)) { //even
```

I also removed the unnecessary `== true`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @MarkByers' answer,

```
while(n.compareTo(one) == -1)
```

Should be

```
while(n.compareTo(one) > 0)
```

or, in pseudocode, `while n > 1`.

You should also take

```
if(n.equals(one) == true && chain_length > greatest_length){
    greatest_length = chain_length;
    greatest_index = i.intValue();
}
```

out of the while loop, as `n` will never equal `one` inside the loop. (And since `n` will [always(?)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)equal `one` after the while loop, you can get rid of the first condition entirely.)

Finally, `i.equals(2)` in

```
for(i.equals(2) ; i.compareTo(target) == -1 ; i = i.add(one))
```

doesn't do anything useful - it just returns false for most of the values.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by  Daniel Fischer your should use long.
Be careful not to do something like
`long a = 987654321`.
Correct version (if you want long): `long a = 987654321L`.
Simple version:

```
int maxChain = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    for (int i = 1_000_000; i > 0; i--) {
        int chain = 0;
        long n = i;
        while (n != 1) {
            if ((n & 1) != 1) { //Is even
                n = n / 2;
                chain++;
            } else { //Is odd
                n = 3 * n + 1;
                chain++;
            }
        }
        if (chain > maxChain) {
            maxChain = chain;
            answer = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
    System.out.println(maxChain);
```